# How to Deploy Laravel + NodeJs + Socket.io Project

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, express, socket.io

I created a real-time app using laravel and socket.io + nodejs, but I don't know how could I deploy it

Comment: Which type of server you have used for host?

Comment: @Irfan I don't know what to do so I asked what server should I use !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you plan to scale in the future. One possibility, especially if you are bootstrapping a project and don't want to spend a lot of time on infrastructure is to:

1. On a CI tool(Jenkins/TravisCI/Bamboo etc..) you build a "package", most usually a compressed tar that contains ready-to-run copies of the 3 projects.
2. Using the CI tool, push your package to the server(using SCP maybe).
3. Manually, execute a "rollout" script, that basically unpacks the package, run migrations(if any), bind ports and hot-reload services(php-fpm, etc..)

Later on, you can have different servers for different projects, have a docker-based infrastructure, setup a CD pipeline where packages get deployed automatically, etc...